# ndb python appengine odd behavior models referencing each other

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

In referencing models with KeyProperty it seems one has to initialize the model before its referenced
Have I missed some bit of information here?

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

#initialize here
class Vessel(ndb.Model):
    pass

class Manifest(ndb.Model):
    vessellist = ndb.KeyProperty(Vessel)

class Vessel(ndb.Model):
    manifest = ndb.KeyProperty(Manifest)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behavior. If you want to avoid putting your models in a specific order and you want cross references like that, you can reference a model with a string instead of the model class:

```
class Manifest(ndb.Model):
    vessellist = ndb.KeyProperty('Vessel')

class Vessel(ndb.Model):
    manifest = ndb.KeyProperty('Manifest')
```